# Update a value in a destroy method in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I make a clone system in Laravel. I want to clone activities.

When I click on "Clone", my line is cloned and receives as the value in the column "parent_id" the ID of the original.

The original gets a value of 1 in the "hasClone" column.

But when I want to delete a clone, in my destroy method, I try to set hasClone (the original entry) to NULL before deleting the clone.

Here is my code :

```
  public function destroyChanges(Activity $activity)
  {

    $parentActivity = Activity::findOrFail($activity->parent_id)->first();
    $parentActivity->hasClone = NULL;
    $parentActivity->save();

    $activity->delete();

    return redirect()->to('/admin/activity/');
  }
```

Here is my route :

```
Route::delete('activity/destroyChanges/{id}', ['as' => 'cancel.activity', 'uses' => 'ActivityCrudController@destroyChanges']);
```

Here is my button :

```
{{ Form::open([ 'method'  => 'DELETE', 'route' => [ 'cancel.activity', $entry->getKey() ] ])  }}
    <button class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-ban"></i> {{ trans('backpack::crud.cancel') }}</button>
{{ Form::close() }}
```

The entry of the clone is deleted correctly. But he does not update the original entry. How to do ? thank you very much

EDIT : I also tried that :

```
 public function destroyChanges($id)
  {
    $activity = Activity::findOrFail($id);

    $parentActivity = Activity::where('id', '=', $activity->parent_id)->first();
    $parentActivity->hasClone = NULL;
    $parentActivity->save();

    $activity->delete();

    return redirect()->to('/admin/activity/');
  }
```

Even if I put a die (); in the destroy method, he ignores it. Why does not it take it into account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define parent method in your model and access the parent like the best answer in the following toppic:

[How to implement a self referencing (parent_id) model in Eloquent Orm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20292329/how-to-implement-a-self-referencing-parent-id-model-in-eloquent-orm)

when you access to that can change hasClone field and save that before the update.

Like this:

```
 $parentActivity = $activity->parent()->first();
 $parentActivity->hasClone = null;
 $parentActivity->save();
```

Ensure to have something like this in your activity model:

```
public function parent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Activity', 'parent_id');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your great answer ! Unfortunately I still have the same problem ... I feel that my method destroy is not taken into account, or in any case, everything I do inside. However, the entry is removed well

Comment: check if $parentActivity->id has value when you get it($parentActivity = $activity->parent()->first();). ifi it has value it may null can not put in hasClone in  not parent method in the model did not work successfully